# Referencing initializer 'init(destination:label:)' on 'NavigationLink'

Tags: ios, list, swiftui

I'm trying to make a `List` but getting error as below code.

```
struct BookView: View {

    var books : [BookModel] = []
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List(self.books, id: \.self) { book in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(book.title ?? "Unknown Title")) {
                    BooksRow(book: book)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BookModel: Hashable {
    var title: String?
    var author: String?
}

struct BooksRow {

    let book : BookModel
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(book.title ?? "Unknown Title")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(book.author ?? "Unknown Author")
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

> Error : Referencing initializer 'init(destination:label:)' on 'NavigationLink' requires that 'BooksRow' conform to 'View'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fix

```
struct BooksRow: View { // << here !!

    let book : BookModel
    var body: some View {

    // ... your other code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct BooksRow: View { // Now it conforms to View-Protocol

        let book : BookModel
        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                Text(book.title ?? "Unknown Title")
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(book.author ?? "Unknown Author")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
```